# Problem with code combining excel files using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlwings

I have a large number of excel files in a folder on my computer, let's say 100. Each of the excel files has one sheet in it. I want to merge all the excel files into one single file with 100 sheets. I have the code below which works but I have a couple of major problems with it. Here is the code:

```
import os
import xlwings as xw

Path = r"C:\Folder"

mainfile = xw.Book()

for filename in os.listdir(Path):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx") or filename.endswith(".xlsm"):
        wb = xw.books.open(os.path.join(Path, filename))
        ws = wb.sheets(1)
        ws.api.Copy(Before = mainfile.sheets(1).api)
        continue
    else:
        continue

mainfile.save(r"C:\Folder\mainfile.xlsx")
mainfile.app.quit()
```

Here are the issues that I was hoping I could get some help with:

1) This code works when I have a small number of small excel files, but it won't work with a larger number of large files. The reason is that the code literally opens every single file then combines them and then closes them all. Is there a way this could be avoided (it gets too slow, as some files are like 80MB)? Basically, can I make it so that the files get combined without them actually being opened in excel?

2) How can I add a piece of code to this to check if "mainfile.xlsx" already exists, and delete it if it already exists before running the rest of the code and creating the a new file named "mainfile.xlsx" again?

I'm open to suggestions if there's a better way to do this with something other than xlwings. I tried win32.client but it stops working after a while and won't work again until I restart my computer. I didn't have much luck with openpyxl either.

Comment: `xlrd` is another one you can try.